# Error building react-create-library with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, package, material-ui

I was looking to create my own React package using `create-react-library`. After installing and following [the guide](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/create-react-library), I've encountered the following error when building my project:

```
Error: 'ForwardRef' is not exported by node_modules/react-is/index.js, imported by node_modules/@material-ui/utils/esm/getDisplayName.js
```

This is somehow expected in case you're working with Material UI, as stated in the guide.
The solution is in the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this error make sure your package.json's devDependecies and peerDependencies include both react and material-ui/core dependecies. Should look similar to:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2"
},
```

Then run `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json` and build again.

Comment: Others might find this solution helpful as well https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/react-modern-library-boilerplate/issues/29#issuecomment-635883117